# npm start fail today with following error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

when I test my code today at react, I fail to start the dev server, and the error shows as blow.

> material@2.0.0 start /Users/linyujie/Files/Softprofiles/SourceCode/successmanagerreact
>   npm run serve:dev

```
> material@2.0.0 serve:dev /Users/linyujie/Files/Softprofiles/SourceCode/successmanagerreact
> webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000 --open --env dev

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:3000
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1351:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1392:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1501:7)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:141:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:678:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! material@2.0.0 serve:dev: `webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000 --open --env dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the material@2.0.0 serve:dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/linyujie/.npm/_logs/2018-06-25T04_55_36_232Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! material@2.0.0 start: `npm run serve:dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the material@2.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/linyujie/.npm/_logs/2018-06-25T04_55_36_255Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I don't know what happened, It used to be fine and I didn't change anything on webpack setup

Comment: Something is already using port 3000 so it throws an error

Answer (score 2):

The port 3000 is in use. Try to use netstat to find the PID of the process that is using the port. And stop/kill the process if you do not need it. This link might be handy for [windows](https://therealdanvega.com/blog/2015/04/16/windows-kill-process-by-port-number) and this for [mac](https://blog.jayway.com/2012/09/08/finding-the-pid-listening-on-a-specific-port-on-mac-os-x/) to find the process listening on the port.

Answer (score 1):

as the error said: `Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:3000`, it means there is an application currently using the same IP & port: `0.0.0.0:3000`. If you're not sure which application is using, maybe you can try closing all the command prompt and launch only your application.